# OrientDB - absent values in automatic SB-Tree index

Tags: sql, indexing, orientdb

I'm working with OrientDB Enterprise Server v2.1.13 and have faced some problems I can't find explanation and solution for yet.

It seems that automatic composite SB-Tree index works improperly and doesn't index new values (or I misunderstand something).
A have the following edge classes:

```
CREATE CLASS ACTION EXTENDS E CLUSTERS 0 ABSTRACT

CREATE PROPERTY ACTION.out LINK
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.out MANDATORY true
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.out NOTNULL true

CREATE PROPERTY ACTION.in LINK
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.in MANDATORY true
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.in NOTNULL true

CREATE PROPERTY ACTION.action STRING
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.action MANDATORY true

CREATE PROPERTY ACTION.status STRING
  ALTER PROPERTY ACTION.status DEFAULT 'NEW'

CREATE INDEX ACTION.out_action_in ON ACTION (out, action, in) UNIQUE

CREATE CLASS LINK EXTENDS ACTION CLUSTERS 8
  ALTER CLASS LINK CLUSTERSELECTION balanced

CREATE INDEX LINK.out_action_in ON LINK (out, action, in) UNIQUE
```

Then we do inserts:

```
CREATE EDGE LINK FROM #12:0 TO #30:0 SET action = 'a';
```

We can SELECT and see that it was inserted correctly into the database:

```
orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action = 'a';

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
0   |#36:0|LINK  |a     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
```

Now let's create SB-Tree NOTUNIQUE index (the default):

```
CREATE INDEX LINK.action_status ON LINK (action, status) NOTUNIQUE
```

Now we CREATE a new record:

```
CREATE EDGE LINK FROM #12:0 TO #30:0 SET action = 'b';
orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
0   |#36:0|LINK  |a     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
1   |#37:8|LINK  |b     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
```

Now we try to SELECT the 'a' and 'b' values:

```
orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action = 'a'; 

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
0   |#36:0|LINK  |a     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.001 sec(s).

orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action = 'b';

0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.001 sec(s).
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
Profiled command     '{fullySortedByIndex:false,compositeIndexUsed:1,involvedIndexes:[1],limit:-1,fetchingFromTargetElapsed:0,indexIsUsedInOrderBy:false,user:#5:0,elapsed:1.116033,resultType:collection,resultSize:0}' in 0,002000 sec(s):
{"@type":"d","@version":0,"fullySortedByIndex":false,"compositeIndexUsed":1,"involvedIndexes":["LINK.action_status"],"limit":-1,"fetchingFromTargetElapsed":0,"indexIsUsedInOrderBy":false,"user":"#5:0","elapsed":1.116033,"resultType":"collection","resultSize":0,"@fieldTypes":"compositeIndexUsed=l,involvedIndexes=e,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,user=x,elapsed=f"}
```

But -- if you SELECT it using IN() -- it's there:

```
orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action in ['b'];

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------
0   |#37:7|LINK  |b     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
Profiled command '{documentReads:1,current:#36:1,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass:1,recordReads:1,limit:-1,fetchingFromTargetElapsed:0,evaluated:1,user:#5:0,elapsed:0.666479,resultType:collection,resultSize:1}' in 0,002000 sec(s):
{"@type":"d","@version":0,"documentReads":1,"current":"#36:1","documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass":1,"recordReads":1,"limit":-1,"fetchingFromTargetElapsed":0,"evaluated":1,"user":"#5:0","elapsed":0.666479,"resultType":"collection","resultSize":1,"@fieldTypes":"documentReads=l,current=x,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,evaluated=l,user=x,elapsed=f"}
```

Any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: Hi, could you add issue on GitHub and SQL team will analyse your query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my workaround is to use the Hash index, which seems to work fine in my case.

```
DROP INDEX LINK.action_status;
CREATE INDEX LINK.action_status ON LINK (action, status) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX;

orientdb {db=userdata}>     CREATE EDGE LINK FROM #12:0 TO #30:0 SET action = 'c';                   

Created edge '[LINK#38:4{action:c,out:#12:0,in:#30:0,status:NEW} v1]' in 0,003000 sec(s). 

orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK;                                         

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status 
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
0   |#36:0|LINK  |a     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
1   |#37:8|LINK  |b     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
2   |#38:4|LINK  |c     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 

3 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s). 

orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action = 'c';                                         

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status 
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
0   |#38:4|LINK  |c     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s). 

orientdb {db=userdata}> SELECT FROM LINK WHERE action in ['c']; 

----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
#   |@RID |@CLASS|action|out  |in   |status 
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 
0   |#38:4|LINK  |c     |#12:0|#30:0|NEW   
----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+------ 

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
```